# MySQL 5.5.9 and mysql.proc error

Tags: mysql

Recently I updated mysql to 5.5.9. The server seems works but I got the following line in mysql.err log

```
Incorrect definition of table mysql.proc: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERRO
```

I have already run mysql_upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [this solution](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59364). It's working for me.